# get entire contents of a div

Tags: jquery

```
var thisWish = $(#div1).children('p,blockquote,.name').html();

<div id="1">
   <p>Hello</p>
   <blockquote> my name is </blockquote>
   <p class="name">Callum</p>
</div>
```

How can i put the entire contents of a div into a variable? I dont justwant the html of each variable, i need the elements aswell, so basically i need

```
thisWish = <p>Hello</p>
       <blockquote> my name is </blockquote>
       <p class="name">Callum</p>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
thisWish = $('div#1').html()
```

Comment: btw: feel free to mark the question as answered (if it indeed is) ;)

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
 thisWish = $('div#1').html()
```